# How does this regex divide text into sentences?

Tags: php, regex, perl

I know this regex divides a text into sentences. Can someone help me understand how?

```
/(?<!\..)([\?\!\.])\s(?!.\.)/
```

Comment: Not by itself, it doesn't.  You'll get better answers if you post more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Portions:

- `([\?\!\.])\s`: split by ending character (`.`,`!`,or `?`) which is followed by a whitespace character (space, tab, newline)
- `(?<!\..)` where the characters before this 'ending character' arent a  `.`+anything
- `(?!.\.)` after the whitespace character any character directly followed by any `.` isn't allowed.

Those look-ahead (`(?!`) & look-behind (`(?<!`) assertions mainly seem to prevent splitting on (whitespaced?) abbreviations (`q. e. d.` etc.).

Answer (score 14):

You can use [YAPE::Regex::Explain](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAPE-Regex-Explain/) to decipher Perl regular expressions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAPE::Regex::Explain;

my $re = qr/(?<!\..)([\?\!\.])\s(?!.\.)/;
print YAPE::Regex::Explain->new($re)->explain();

__END__

The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(?<!\..)([\?\!\.])\s(?!.\.))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\?\!\.]                 any character of: '\?', '\!', '\.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 5):

There is the [Regular Expression Analyzer](http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/analyzer.html?regex=/%28%3F%3C%21%5C..%29%28%5B%5C%3F%5C%21%5C.%5D%29%5Cs%28%3F%21.%5C.%29/&env=env_perl) which will do quite the same as [toolic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832945/understanding-a-specific-regex/3833019#3833019) already suggested - but completely webbased.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?         # Find a group (don't capture)
<          # before the following regular expression
!          # that does not match
\.         # a literal "."
.          # followed by 1 character
)          # (End look-behind group)
(          # Start a group (capture it to $1)
[\?\!\.]   # Containing any one of the characters in the following set "?!."
)          # End group $1
\s         # followed by a whitespace character " ", \t, etc.
(?         # Followed by a group (don't capture)
           # after the preceding regular expression
!          # that does not have
.          # 1 character
\.         # followed by a literal "."
)          # (End look-ahead group)
```

Answer (score 2):

The first part `(?<!\..)` is a negative look-behind. It specifies a pattern which invalidates the match. In this case it's looking for two characters--the first a period and the other one any character.

The second part is a standard capture/group, which could be better expressed: `([?!.])` (you don't need the escapes *in* the class brackets), that is a sentence ending punctuation character.

The next part is a *single* (*??*) white-space character: `\s`

And the last part is a negative look-ahead: `(?!.\.)`. Again it is guarding against the case of a single character followed by a period.

This should work, *relatively* well. But I don't think I would recommend it. I don't see what the coder was getting at trying to make sure that *just* a period wasn't the second most recent character, or that it wasn't the second one to come.

I mean if you are looking to split on terminal punctuation, why don't you want to guard against the same class being two-back or two-ahead? Instead it relies on periods not being there. Thus a more regular expression would be:

```
/(?<![?!.].)([?!.])\s(?!.[?!.])/
```

Comment: I suppose the two-back requirement stops it from splitting after "G.E.D.", although it does nothing at all to protect against "Dr." or "Mr." The after-space bit is more mysterious and possibly a bit cargo-culty.

Comment: @hobbs: Well I was thinking about abbreviations, but I also thought that it doesn't guard against spaced out abbreviations that you sometimes see like "U. S. A."